# web image gallery issues: database id index holes and pagination query

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables, image-gallery

I am working on a web image gallery done in php.
At poit where I am I can upload images from db, create thumbinails from them and delete images  that I don't want anymore.
Unfortunately I have some issues with the layout structure.

I want to create pages that can hold a maximum of 10 images (for example).
So in the 1st page there are images from 0 to 9, in the 2nd page images 10-19 and so on.

The first problem regards the id of the images stored in mysql database. Every uploaded image has its id number. So, if I add for the first time 10 images, I get the relative id 0,1,2,3...10 related to its pic. But if I delete the image id 3, I break the index progression. So the new index progression became 0,1,2,**4**,5 etc...This is bad to me because I need to keep always the classic idexing but I don't know what I have to do.

The second issue reards how to manage pages and their content.

I use

```
if (isset($_GET['page_id']))
```

to create various numbers of pages.
Then I store the page id into a varible. Al so I keep the nmaximum number of images*page into one other variable.

```
$pageid = $_GET['page'];
$imgmax = 10;
```

At tis point is time to work with queries.
I thought to use this kind of query:

```
$sql='SELECT image_id, image_url, thumb_url FROM images LIMIT $imgmax OFFSET ($pageid*$imgmax)-$imgmax';
```

But I was wrong. This kind of query doesn't work.
I think because I cant pass a php variabile into a query.
But, from there, I cant walk forward because I am at a dead point.

Some help, please?
It will be very very appreciated!

Best regards e Thanks for the attention.

Matteo

Comment: you may be looking for `LIMIT ($pageid*$imgmax)-$imgmax, $imgmax` - also, surround your query with double quotes or it will be treated as string literal

Comment: thanks Kai Qing, I tried a different solution with  php and it seems to work weel (if u are interested, see my answer to my question). Anyway, thanks a lot for your answer, I really appreciated it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a fast solution for these issues of mine.
Rather than use query's commands, I stored all the rows of the table in an array ad then I use the [b]array_slice()[/b] function to selects parts of the array. This works fine for me. Here u are quick summary

```
//after "img_url" selection from "images" table:

foreach ($results as $row) {
    $images[] = array( 'img_url' => $row['img_url']);
}

$select = array_slice($images, (($page_id*$images_maxnumber_eachpage)-$images_maxnumber_eachpage), $images_maxnumber_eachpage);
```

Maybe this will bel helpful for some other people!

Thanks anyway. :)

regards

Matteo

Comment: It's an interesting solution that's ok for reasonably small data sets, but still, this is a very elementary issue for databases to handle. In the end, do what works for you.